# Take input value and display in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cant for the life of me figure out why the following is not working. I took if from the W3school example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange).

Basically I want to take the value from the input text when it changes and modify another div to include the value. I only want the div to show the new value, but I do want it to change it each time so I figured the onchange was the way to go.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var div = document.getElementById('divID');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + x.value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onchange="myFunction()">
<p>When you leave the input field, a function is triggered which transforms the input text to upper case.</p>

<div id="divID"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for all the help on this one.

Comment: “When you leave the input field, a function is triggered which transforms the input text to upper case.” Where is the function?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the piece of code where x.value was defined. Chancho's assumption was right on the money.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 problems, first is that x is undefined.
second you should use another trigger for this for this to happen each time.

try this out:

```
    function myFunction()
    {
        var input = document.getElementById('fname')
        var div = document.getElementById('divID');
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + input.value;
    }
```

and change your html to:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeypress="myFunction()">
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks man, your inference was spot on.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is undefined in your function, it should be `document.getElementById('fname')`.

And if you want to change the div each time you press the key, use `onkeyup` or `onkeypress` instead of `onchange`.

Answer (score 1):

You may change `x.value` to `document.getElementById("fname").value`, if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function input(){
            var input_taker = document.getElementById('email').value;
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = input_taker;
        }
    </script>


</head>

<form method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email@example.com" id="email"  onchange="input()">
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save">

</form>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so check this out - http://jsfiddle.net/2ufnK/2/

The issue is that you need to define x here,

`var x = document.getElementById("fname");`

x now references to the html object.

Then you can just call the, ".value", method to get its text. Then everything else works the way you've written it.