# Modify variable from input and place in new div based on input variable

Tags: javascript, html

This is related to my [last questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754131/take-input-value-and-display-in-another-div/20754208?noredirect=1#20754208), but that already had alot of answers so I did not want to modify it with more stuff to avoid confusion.

I can take the input from the input text with the id 'test', and I can display it on the div labeled 'result', but I am not able to modify the output to div

```
 function createLinks()
    {
      var input = document.getElementById('test')
          if(str.indexOf("VALUE")>=0){
               var lin = "something";
          }
          else {
                   var lin = "somethingelse";
          }
      var div = document.getElementById('result');
      div.innerHTML = lin.value;
    }
```

The HTML is working currently as follows:

```
 <input type="text" id="test" size="16" title="Coming Soon" onkeypress="createLinks()"/>
 <input type="submit" style="margin-left: 10px;" value="Search" class="button1"/>
 <div id="result"></div>
```

I work with mainly CGI and have very limited knowledge of JS so I am probably missing something simple or this plain wont work. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `str` is not defined.

Comment: think all you need to change is if(str to if(input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code to what I think you wanted:

```
function createLinks()
{
    var lin;
  var input = document.getElementById('test');
      if(input.value.indexOf("VALUE")>=0){
           lin = "something";
      }
      else {
               lin = "somethingelse";
      }
  var div = document.getElementById('result');
  div.innerHTML = lin;
}
```

What was wrong was that:

**[1]** `str` was not defined

**[2]** `lin` was not globally defined, so you couldn't access it.

I updated the code so that it will make `result` say `something` if the textbox has `VALUE` typed in it and `somethingelse` if it doesn't, and that you can also press the `Search` button instead of pressing a key.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was missing with the variable definitions. I am going to figure out the best html onevent here soon, but I wanted the `JS` working first.

Answer (score 0):

Try This: `str` not defined and `lin` is the value.

```
function createLinks()
    {
      var input = document.getElementById('test')
          if(input.value.indexOf("VALUE")>=0){
               var lin = "something";
          }
          else {
                var lin = "somethingelse";
          }
      var div = document.getElementById('result');
      div.innerHTML = lin;
    }
```

Comment: No I did not I copied his code and added my changes, Your answer was not there when I started...

Comment: Okay, just making sure so that the public doesn't read **answered 2 mins after Andre.**  Also, I posted that comment *5 mins after Andre.*