# JS Getting input value/name stored in a var

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I have alot pf inputs, and i want to on.('change') get the value or the name of the input as a string so that i can later convert it to a class and inject it onto a div... I may not have been the clearest possible but… any help is good!

the website: http://angusweb.pw

EDIT: the css classes used are from the framework on the site above, i'm developing it

It's below the big green square and the html is

HTML

```
<div class="setFullWH setFlex setFlexSuperCenter setFlexWrap ">

<form id="parentProperties" class="setFlex setFlexWrap setFlexRow">
<div class="setFlex setBasicGrow setBasicShrink setFlexBasis15 setFlexColumn setNoto">
<div class="setBasicGrow setJustifyContentSpcArnd">
<input id="flexParent1" name="flexParent" type="radio">
<label for="flexParent1">seFlexRow</label>
</div>
<div class="setBasicGrow">
<input id="flexParent2" name="flexParent" type="radio">
<label for="flexParent2">setFlexColumn</label>
</div>
<div class="setBasicGrow">
<input id="flexParent3" name="flexParent" type="radio">
<label for="flexParent3">setFlexHAlign</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="setFlex setBasicGrow setBasicShrink setFlexBasis15 setFlexColumn setNoto">
<div class="setBasicGrow">
<input id="flexParent4" name="flexParent" type="radio">
<label for="flexParent4">setFlexVAlign</label>
</div>
<div class="setBasicGrow">
<input id="flexParent5" name="flexParent" type="radio">
<label for="flexParent5">setFlexSuperCenter</label>
</div>
<div class="setBasicGrow">
<input id="flexParent6" name="flexParent" type="radio">
<label for="flexParent6">setAlignContentStart</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="setFlex setBasicGrow setBasicShrink setFlexBasis15 setFlexColumn setNoto">
<div class="setBasicGrow">
<input id="flexParent7" name="flexParent" type="radio">
<label for="flexParent7">setAlignContentEnd</label>
</div>
<div class="setBasicGrow">
<input id="flexParent8" name="flexParent" type="radio">
<label for="flexParent8">setAlignContentCenter</label>
</div>
<div class="setBasicGrow">
<input id="flexParent9" name="flexParent" type="radio">
<label for="flexParent9">setAlignContentStretch</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="setFlex setBasicGrow setBasicShrink setFlexBasis15 setFlexColumn setNoto">
<div class="setBasicGrow">
<input id="flexParent10" name="flexParent" type="radio">
<label for="flexParent10">setAlignContentSpcBetw</label>
</div>
<div class="setBasicGrow">
<input id="flexParent11" name="flexParent" type="radio">
<label for="flexParent11">setAlignContentSpcArr</label>
</div>
<div class="setBasicGrow">
<input id="flexParent12" name="flexParent" type="radio">
<label for="flexParent12">setAlignItemsStart</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="setFlex setBasicGrow setBasicShrink setFlexBasis15 setFlexColumn setNoto">
 <div class="setBasicGrow">
 <input id="flexParent13" name="flexParent" type="radio">
 <label for="flexParent13">setAlignItemsEnd</label>
 </div>
 <div class="setBasicGrow">
 <input id="flexParent14" name="flexParent" type="radio">
 <label for="flexParent14">setAlignItemsCenter</label>
 </div>
 <div class="setBasicGrow">
 <input id="flexParent15" name="flexParent" type="radio">
 <label for="flexParent15">setAlignItemsStretch</label>
 </div>
 </div>

   <div class="setFlex setBasicGrow setBasicShrink setFlexBasis15 setFlexColumn setNoto">
   <div class="setBasicGrow">
   <input id="flexParent16" name="flexParent" type="radio">
   <label for="flexParent16">setAlignItemsBaseline</label>
   </div>
   <div class="setBasicGrow">
   <input id="flexParent17" name="flexParent" type="radio">
   <label for="flexParent17">setFlexWrap</label>
   </div>
   </div>
   </form>
 </div>
```

EDIT: i managed to get the value i wanted, and transform it to a class, and inject to the wanted div… problem is, when i click some other input, i want the class generated by the former to be deleted, or replaced, by the new one…

Comment: So you want to get the value of the inputs? Try and specify the core problem, it helps us and you :)

Comment: This link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754131/take-input-value-and-display-in-another-div[][1]

Comment: [This should help solve your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754131/take-input-value-and-display-in-another-div)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use jQuery? If so then

```
$('input:radio').each(function(){
    $(this).on("click",function(){
        console.log($(this).val()); //To get the value, this returns on/off wether your radio is selected or not
        console.log($(this).attr('name')); // To get the name
        console.log($(this).next('label').text()); //To get the text inside your label
    });
})
```

- Edit: Added jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yingchor/6yqhxa41/3/ for testing and validation purposes.

Comment: can i make this into a re usable function?

Comment: How so? If you just put it inside your `$(document).ready(function(){})` the script will run and your onclick events will be set to your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name and value of an input field with the following in javascript:

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var value = inputs[0].value;
var name = inputs[0].name;

console.log(value);
console.log(name);
```

```html
<input id="inputText" type="text" name="fname" value="a value">
```

Comment: what if i have like 40 inputs? not very pratical to that to all…

Comment: @Miguel I edited the answer to select a list of inputs. You can do this or select an input by a particular name or ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this new element (`<div class="class-name"></div>`) in HTML and inject the name of the selected input(radio) in its class. Here is The code:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="class-name"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#parentProperties input').on('click', function(){
    className = $(this).attr('name');
    $('.class-name').addClass(className);
  });
});
```

Instead of `on.('change')` `on.('click')` is perfect in this case.